# Regex performance degrade over time

Tags: c#, regex

I have wrote a simple test application to check possibility of using regular expressions for my needs. I need to find and substitute all duplicate tags in the provided text file with some unique strings. For example if some text will be found in input file more that once then all its occurrences should be replaced with {1}, and so on.

For this purpose I have create the following snippet:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Integration\Item-26 - Copy.xml"));

        Regex r = new Regex(
            @"(?<exp>\<(?<tag>[^\<\>\s]+)[^\<\>]*\>[^\<\>]+\<\/\k<tag>\>).*\k<exp>", 
            RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

        List<string> values = new List<string>();

        MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(xml.ToString());

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        while (matches.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Match m in matches)
            {
                string matchValue = m.Groups["exp"].Value;
                values.Add(matchValue);
                xml.Replace(matchValue, string.Concat("{" + (values.Count - 1) + "}"));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Analyzed " + matches.Count + " matches, total replacements = " + values.Count);

            matches = r.Matches(xml.ToString());
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("=============== " + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The problem is if I have a large file as an input (>1MB) then each call to find matches takes longer than previous. In the beginning it takes 0.3 sec to call matches.Count. And after 100 iterations it will take more that 1 min.

I have checked the memory usage by the test app - and it consumes almost nothing without any real growth.

What is causing this, and how can I get steady performance?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the compiled attribute first. It might just solve your mistery.

Comment: Have tried this (and other variations of options) - it does not help.

Comment: Hmmm... Do you parse your xml-data with a regex?

I mean this line in your code: "`MatchCollection matches = r.Matches(xml.ToString());`"

Comment: I am using regex to find duplicates in text. Do you have better suggestion?

Comment: What does your profiler say? At least pause the debugger a few times to see where it stops most.

Comment: It spends most time in match.Count. It is the place that force regex to evaluate. The same behavior is exposed if I will not replace anything and just apply the same regex to the same string over and over. The performance degradation is the same.

Comment: this is how the output looks If I will include timings:

Comment: 0,4201097
0,8160535
1,3222799
1,7082787
2,0999917
2,5018408
3,0653143
3,5341894
3,9722492
4,390986
4,7647451
5,2543359 sec

Comment: Actually I was wrong and if I do not change the string - the performance does not degrade. It only happens if in each next iteration the input string is different.

Comment: That `.*` in your regular expression looks suspicious. It will cause a whole lot of backtracking. You might want to change that to be non-greedy, as in `.*?`.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable suggestion but it is still the same problem: applying same regex to the changing string considerably degrades overtime. With your suggestion it finds more replacements at a time but still starts with less than 1 sec per iteration and goes down to 22 sec just after 24 iterations.

Comment: @Amid - The problem is your regular expression.  A regular expression and regex.Match have performance costs.  Sounds like a regex isn't appriate here.

Comment: I understand that the regex is slow. My question is why does it get so considerably slower if repeated several times? My code is very simple and still it manage to get 10 times slower after just 20 iterations of processing 1mb file???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think the problem is. Your regex is:

```
@"(?<exp>\<(?<tag>[^\<\>\s]+)[^\<\>]*\>[^\<\>]+\<\/\k<tag>\>).*\k<exp>"
```

So you're looking for something like:

```
<tag>stuff</tag>lots of stuff here<tag>stuff</tag>
```

During the first iterations, the regex fails quickly as inner tags are replaced, because tags are close together. But as more inner tags are replaced, the space between tags increases. Soon you have:

```
<tag>stuff</tag>hundreds of kilobytes<tag2>other stuff</tag2><tag>stuff</tag>
```

And backtracking starts killing you.

I suspect you can solve this by replacing the `.*` (or `.*?` that I suggested earlier) with `[^\<]*`. Because you know that when you find a `<`, then either you've found a match or it's a definite failure.